# Show: Ergodic implies $f=\text{const a.s.}$

Tags: ergodic-theory

> > Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu,T)$ be a dynamic system in measure theory. Let this system be ergodic. Show then then this implies
> >     $$
> > \forall f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}\mbox{measurable}: f=f\circ T\text{ a.s. }\Rightarrow f=\text{const a.s.}
> > $$

The idea of the proof which we got from the professor is to define the set
$$
\Omega_{kn}:=\left\{\omega\in\Omega| k2^{-n}\leq f(\omega)< (k+1)2^{-n}\right\}.
$$
Because of the measurability of $f$ it is $\Omega_{kn}\in\mathcal{A}$ and
because $f\circ T=f\text{ a.s. }$ it is $T^{-1}(\Omega_{kn})\subset\Omega_{kn}\text{ a.s. }$. So, because the system is ergodic, it is $\mu(\Omega_{kn})=0\text{ or }\mu(\Omega_{kn}^C)=0$.

Additionally $\Omega_{kn}\cap\Omega_{jn}=\emptyset$ for $j,k\in\mathcal{Z}, j\neq k$.

The professor said, that from all this it follows that $\mu(\Omega_{kn})=1$.

Then he consideres $n\to\infty$ getting that $f=\text{ const a.s.}$.

---

Could you please explain me why it follows that $\mu(\Omega_{kn})=1$ and why it is necessary to show this?

Comment: Shouldn't it rather say $\exists! k\in\mathbb Z: \mu(\Omega_{kn}) = 1, \forall j\in\mathbb Z, j\neq k: \mu(\Omega_{jn})=0$ to conclude the proof?

Comment: I do not see your point, can you explain it please?

Comment: Well, if this is shown that means that for any $n$ there is a $k$ such that $f(x) \in [k2^{-n}, (k+1)2^{-n})$ for all $x$, so the values all belong to a small stripe of length $2^{-n}$ which for $n\to\infty$ means the values all belong to a "stripe" of length $0$, i.e. a single point, thus $f(x) = c$ (all of that a.s.)

Comment: Ok, but why does from the ergodicity and the fact that the $\Omega_{kn}$ are disjoint follow that there is (exactly one) k with $\mu(\Omega_{kn})=1$?

Comment: Because all other $\Omega_{jn} \subset \Omega_{kn}^C$ are subsets of a nullset, I'll write it down more elaborately as an answer.

Comment: Why is then $\mu(\Omega_{nk})=1$? Is this a probability measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $j,k\in\mathbb Z$.
Since $\Omega_{kn}\cap\Omega_{jn} = \emptyset \qquad \forall j\neq k$, it follows
$$\Omega_{jn} \subset \Omega_{kn}^C \qquad \forall j \neq k$$
However, for fixed $k$ we know
$$\mu(\Omega_{kn}) = 0 \text{ or } \mu(\Omega_{kn}^C)=0$$
Let $k$ now be such that $\mu(\Omega_{kn}^C)=0$ (and thus by ergodicity and $T^{-1}(\Omega_{kn}) \subset \Omega_{kn}: \mu(\Omega_{kn})=1$). Then we have for all $j\neq k$:
$$\mu(\Omega_{jn}) \stackrel{\Omega_{jn} \text{ measurable}}\leq \mu(\Omega_{kn}^C) = 0$$
This means if we have one such $k$, all other $\Omega_{jn}$ must be nullsets, as claimed.

Comment: Thank you but I have still the question why $\mu(\Omega_{kn})=1$ if  $\mu(\Omega_{kn}^C)=0$. :-)

Comment: And whats with the case that $\mu(\Omega_{kn})=0$ and not $\mu(\Omega_{kn}^C)=0$?

Comment: Then $\mu(\Omega_{kn}^C) = 1$ and thus there must be some other $j$ with the property, since
$$\Omega_{kn}^C = \bigcup_{j\in\mathbb Z, j\neq k} \Omega_{jn}$$

Comment: Ok, I think I almost got it. The only thing that I do not understand yet is why from $\mu(\Omega_{kn})=0$ it follows $\mu(\Omega_{kn}^C)=1$ resp. why from $\mu(\Omega_{kn}^C)=0$ it follows $\mu(\Omega_{kn})=1$.

Comment: You use ergodicity for both $T^{-1}(\Omega_{kn}^C) \subset \Omega_{kn}^C$ (acquired by decomposition into the other $\Omega_{jn}$) and $T^{-1}(\Omega_{kn}) \subset \Omega_{kn}$ and then mingle the two ;)

Comment: Does "ergodicity" means for you that $\forall A\in\mathcal{A}: T^{-1}(A)\subset A\Rightarrow \mu(A)\in\left\{0,1\right\}$? If yes, I can see it. But I know ergodicity as $\forall A\in\mathcal{A}: T^{-1}(A)\subset A\Rightarrow \mu(A)=0\text{ or }\mu(A^C)=0$ and in this case I do not see why the measure of the complement has to be 1. - - And another question: Is $\Omega=\biguplus_k \Omega_{kn}$?

Comment: @math12 The earlier: yes; the latter: yes, since $\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb Z} [k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}) = \mathbb R$

Comment: Is the other implication true, too? I take a $A\in\mathcal{A}$ with $T^{-1}(A)\subset A$. Then $1_A=1_A\circ T$ and so especially $1_A=1_A\circ T$ a.s., right? Then $1_A=\text{ const a.s.}$. Now does this mean that $\mu(A)\in\left\{0,1\right\}$?

Comment: I would say YES, because $1_A=\text{const.}$ means $1_A=1\text{ a.s.}$ or $1_A=0\text{ a.s.}$ and then it is $\mu(A)=\int_A\, d\mu=\int_{\Omega}1\, d\mu=1$ resp. $\mu(A)=\int_{A}\, d\mu=\int_{\Omega}0\, d\mu=0$.

Comment: By the way: What is $\lim_{n\to\infty} [k2^{-n}, (k+1)2^{-n})$...?

Comment: @math12 in this case the limit would not be well-defined, you have to take $\bigcup_k$ first. If you really want to define this limit, it should be either $\emptyset$ or $\{0\}$.